# Repeat loop every 5 minutes in php

Tags: php

How to repeat a loop every 15mins in PHP. I am new to coding in PHP please give me some tutorial or code. Please guys. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: what's the loop do? sounds like you want a cron job

Comment: yes, build a php script and run it with a cron job

Comment: please elaborate on what are you trying to do and some sample code which you have tried.

Comment: The loop have to fetch data from MySQL.

Comment: you could have search for "how to run a php job repeatedly" or "schedule a php job" and gotten an answer for yourself in far less time than it would've taken to write your question in the first place.

Comment: Your title says 5, your "question" 15

Comment: while ( 1 ) {
sleep ( 900 );
echo "Crawling on the go ..." . time ();
echo "<br />";
echo str_pad ( " ", 4096 );
flush ();
}

Comment: Reload/Refresh automatically every 15 minutes?

Comment: what do you do with the fetched data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### As were said before, what you actually need is:

1. To build your **PHP** script which does all the logic you need **without looping** ( for example: fetching DB data and encoding JSON )
2. Configure a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job which will run the **PHP** script every **X** time.

#### Example:

- example.php - *here will be all your DB fetching and encoding logic*
- /etc/crontab - *the location of this file depends on your OS*.

Write `crontab -e`in the linux shell
Add this line to the end of your crontab file: 
`*/15 * * * * /path/to/your/php/file`

And save it

Now every 15 minutes your **PHP** file should run and do you what you want it to do.

P.S. if you see that your **PHP** script is not running every 15 minutes, you need to verify that crond service is running: `service crond status` in linux shell